# How can I use Tomselect in an easyadmin filter

Tags: symfony, easyadmin, tom-select

In easyadmin we can use the pretty cool Tomselect library in an entity crud form https://symfony.com/doc/current/EasyAdminBundle/fields/AssociationField.html

But how can I use this library in a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use tomselect in a layout from easy admin (which then include easy admin javascript), you can define a select as a tomselect widget.

Just add html attribute `data-ea-widget="ea-autocomplete"` on your select and it should become a tom select. This is done automatically when using a select in a form but nothing prevent you from doing it manually.

Or if you are using webpack, you could just import TomSelect and use it.

```
import TomSelect from 'tom-select'

new TomSelect('#select_id')
```